# How do I Enqueue styles/scripts on Certain /wp-admin Pages?

Tags: wp-admin, wp-enqueue-script, admin-menu, wp-enqueue-style, admin-init

I have two simple functions that load stuff using [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), something like these:

```
function admin_custom_css()
{ wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_name', 'stylesheet.css') }; 

function admin_custom_js 
{ wp_enqueue_script( 'javascript_file', 'script.js') };
```

... and a few admin pages, created with [`add_menu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) and [`add_submenu_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page)

```
function my_menu() {
   add_menu_page('Page 1', 'bar', 'something', 'else', 'foo');
   add_submenu_page( 'theme_menu', 'Subpage 1', 'Subpage', 'something', 'else', 'foo'); 
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu');
```

**How do I load my two functions only on these pages?**

Right now I'm using:

```
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_custom_css' ); 
add_action('admin_init', 'admin_custom_js' );
```

But it loads my files on every admin page, which is not nice at all.

Can I do this via one simple line in `functions.php` or have to enqueue them within my pages separately (I prefer the first option strongly, since I'd have to edit a lot of admin-page-creating-functions).

Thanks!

Comment: See official documentation examples https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/enqueuing/#enqueue

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Target_a_Specific_Admin_Page

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page` both return the page's "hook suffix", which can be used to identify the page with certain hooks. As such, you can use that suffix in combination with the variable hooks `admin_print_styles-{$hook_suffix}` and `admin_print_scripts-{$hook_suffix}` to specifically target these pages.

```
function my_menu() {
   $menu = add_menu_page( 'Page 1', 'bar', 'something', 'else', 'foo' );
   $submenu = add_submenu_page( 'theme_menu', 'Subpage 1', 'Subpage', 'something', 'else', 'foo' );

   add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $menu, 'admin_custom_css' );
   add_action( 'admin_print_styles-' . $submenu, 'admin_custom_css' );

   add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' . $menu, 'admin_custom_js' );
   add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-' . $submenu, 'admin_custom_js' );
}
```

I find this to be a clean method for adding all of this because it's all handled within the one function. If you decide to remove this functionality, simply remove the call to the one function.

Comment: This answer is not technically correct. the [Codex for `admin_print_scripts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts) states "`admin_print_scripts` **should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts**." The answer by @TomAuger is actually the correct one, although not optimal. It would be beneficial if the WP team added an `admin_enqueue_scripts-(hookname)` hook though...

Comment: It took me 3 days to find this answer which was really helpful for me :) Thanks :)

Comment: @DavidGard, you should probably look at these https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_styles-hook_suffix/ , https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_scripts-hook_suffix/

Comment: @hkchakladar My comment is nearly four years old... If it's no longer relevant, by all means add a more up to date comment explaining why.

Answer (score 90):

The problem with @tollmanz answer is that since you're hooking off of the -print-styles and -print-scripts hooks, you must generate the HTML to load your scripts manually. This is not optimal, since you don't get the nice dependency and versioning that comes with `wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()`. It also doesn't let you put things in the footer if that's a better place for them.

So, back to the OP's question: what's the best way to ensure that I can enqueue JS / CSS on specific admin pages only?

1. Hook off the "load-{$my_admin_page}" action to only do things when it's your specific plugin's admin page that's loaded, and then
2. Hook off the "admin_enqueue_scripts" action to properly add your `wp_enqueue_script` calls.

Seems like a bit of a pain, but it's actually very easy to implement. From the top:

```
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_my_admin_menus' ); // hook so we can add menus to our admin left-hand menu

    /**
     * Create the administration menus in the left-hand nav and load the JavaScript conditionally only on that page
     */
    function add_my_admin_menus(){
        $my_page = add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', MY_ADMIN_CAPABILITY, 'menu-slug', 'show_page_content' );

        // Load the JS conditionally
        add_action( 'load-' . $my_page, 'load_admin_js' );
    }

    // This function is only called when our plugin's page loads!
    function load_admin_js(){
        // Unfortunately we can't just enqueue our scripts here - it's too early. So register against the proper action hook to do it
        add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin_js' );
    }

    function enqueue_admin_js(){
        // Isn't it nice to use dependencies and the already registered core js files?
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', INCLUDES_URI . '/js/my_script.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-tabs' ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 - This is the way to go IMO. The individual namespaced (someaction-$hook) hooks are nice for 1 or 2 actions, but if you're authoring a plugin, you may need to do a lot of different things just on your option page(s) which makes this method really convenient.  I usually just add 1 action to the `load-$hook` hook that fires my `option_page_actions` function to which I may add many other hooks/filters etc.  Because those actions are only called on the page of choice, hooks beyond that point don't need to use the namespaced hooks (as you have shown), which is much more efficient & intuitive.

Comment: Hi, is this way still supported? load_admin_js is never calling

Comment: Sure it's still supported. Line 206 of admin.php. Been there since 2.6, and unlikely to go away any time soon (ever).

Comment: Looking at my answer now, I believe that explicitly enqueueing jquery-ui-core and jquery-ui-tabs is entirely superfulous, since those scripts are already registered. You just need to call them in the dependency. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Works perfectly with WordPress 4.9.6

Comment: Used it within WPPB (in a class) + WP 5.4 and it still works.

Comment: It's a cute solution but you can also use the $hook_suffix parameter of admin_enqueue_scripts action. I like this more tho, i don't know why. You can use anonymous callbacks to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 16):

If you use [`get_current_screen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen), you can detect what the page you're on is. There is an example in the codex article that I linked which shows how to use `get_current_screen()` with `add_options_page()`, this method will work for any admin page.

Answer (score 6):

As @mor7ifer mentioned above, you can use the native WordPress function **get_current_screen()**. If you loop through the output of this function, e.g.:

```
$current_screen = get_current_screen();
foreach($current_screen as $key => $value) {
    error_log(print_r($key,1));
}
```

... you'll notice a key called ***base***. I use this detect what page I'm on and enqueue, dequeue like so:

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'some_hook_function')* ):

public function some_hook_function(){

    // # only register and queue scripts & styles on POST edit screen of admin
    $current_page = get_current_screen()->base;
    if($current_page == 'post' || $current_page == 'page') {

        wp_enqueue_script('datetimepicker', plugins_url('assets/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js', __FILE__), array('jquery', 'jquery-ui-datepicker', 'jquery-ui-slider'), '1.9.1', true);

        wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-datepicker', plugins_url('assets/jquery-ui.min.css', __FILE__), array(), '1.11.2', 'all');


    } else { // # if not on post page, deregister and dequeue styles & scripts

        wp_dequeue_script('datetimepicker');
        wp_dequeue_style('jquery-ui-datepicker');

    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was wondering the same thing. There's a modern version that uses `admin_enqueue_scripts`:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
  $settingsPage = add_options_page('Settings', 'Mortgage Calculator', 'manage_options', 'mortgagecalculator', function () {
    echo "<div id='app'></div>";
  });
  /**
   * Include the ember admin scripts only on pages where it's needed.
   */
  add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts", function ($hook) use ($settingsPage){
    if($hook !== $settingsPage){
      return;
    }
    // Remove default jQuery since Ember provides its own.
    wp_dequeue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('ember-vendor', plugins_url("admin/assets/vendor.js", __FILE__));
    wp_enqueue_script('ember-project', plugins_url("admin/assets/mortgage-plugin-ember-admin.js", __FILE__), ['ember-vendor']);
    wp_enqueue_script('ember-live-reload', "http://localhost:4200/ember-cli-live-reload.js");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

To make it, you have to find the admin page name first. Add `admin_enqueue_scripts` with `wp_die($hook)` and go to your specific plugin page, You will see the page name.

```
function my_plugin_scripts($hook) {
    wp_die($hook);
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_scripts' );
```

> settings_page_plugging_info

Now copy the page name and use it in condition to load the scripts on the specific page.

```
function my_plugin_scripts($hook) {
    if ( 'settings_page_plugging_info' != $hook ) {
        return;
    }

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_custom_script', plugins_url('js/file.js', __FILE__));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_scripts' );
```

Comment: This is the correct approach. **All** the previous answers to this post are overly convoluted and/or plain wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You could take [`@tollmanz`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/4850/tollmanz) [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/41224/9579), and expand on it slightly, allowing for conditional usage as well...

**Example:**

```
/* Add admin pages */   
function my_admin_pages(){
    $menu = array();
    $menu['main_page'] = add_menu_page('Page 1', 'bar', 'something', 'else', 'foo');
    $menu['sub_page'] = add_submenu_page('theme_menu', 'Subpage 1', 'Subpage', 'something', 'else', 'foo');
    foreach($menu as $key => $value){
        if($key == 'main_page'){
            /* Print styles on only the main page. */
            add_action('admin_print_styles-'.$value, 'print_styles');
        }
        /* Print scripts on all of our admin pages. */
        add_action('admin_print_scripts-'.$value, 'print_scripts');
    }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_pages');
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_scripts):

> `admin_print_scripts` mainly used to echo inline javascript. `admin_print_scripts` should not be used to enqueue styles or scripts on the admin pages. Use [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts) instead."

Same with [`admin_print_styles`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_print_styles).

Comment: Look at these https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_scripts-hook_suffix/ , https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_print_styles-hook_suffix/

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_my_admin_menus' ); 

function add_my_admin_menus() {
    $GLOBALS['my_page'] = add_menu_page( 'Page Title', 'Menu Title', MY_ADMIN_CAPABILITY, 'menu-slug', 'show_page_content');
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_admin_js');
}

function enqueue_admin_js($hook) {
    if($GLOBALS['my_page'] === $hook) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-core' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tabs' );
        // Isn't it nice to use dependencies and the already registered core js files?
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', INCLUDES_URI . '/js/my_script.js', array( 'jquery-ui-core', 'jquery-ui-tabs' ) );
    }
}
```