# Integrating the Wordpress admin panel with a frontend theme

Tags: customization, admin-bar

I am building a Wordpress membership site where I need to collect user generated content in form of:
-posts
-events
-classified ads

I am using three plugins to accomplish this. However I need to integrate the style of the admin panel with the design of the site for certain user roles.

Is this possible without having to build a custom plugin?

Comment: Yes it is. By default, any user role, any user - when signing in gets access to the dashboard area. Naturally privileges determine what they see, buts its the admin UI. If you are circumventing that by disallowing users to access the dashboard, either through code of your own or through the plugins, then we'll need to see some more info. For instance, a site I am working on now allows user registration, posting and content management from the front end only and restricts access to the dashboard. This is not an out of the box feature. So what have you tried? What errors (if any) are you seeing?

Comment: I am working with a membership plugin called PaidMembershipsPro. It gives me shortcodes to add the user registration process into pages. However when the members need to post up articles, events or classified ads the theme switches to the Wordpress admin style. This is freaking my client out and I think they would prefer a more seamless approach.

Comment: Ok, so now you're saying the opposite of wanting to integrate the style of the admin panel with the design of the site. What you mean is that you want your users to publish content from the front end, so it appears that they never leave the site, maintaining the design and layout, leaving only the admin dashboard for you and your client.

Comment: Well put that is exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

To override the CSS on the admin side (in order to make it match your theme) you can enqueue your own css:

```
function admin_custom_css()
     { wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_name', 'stylesheet.css') };
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_custom_css' );
```

This will insert your custom css on every admin page.  See this answer for how to do this for certain admin pages only:

[How do I enqueue styles/scripts on certain /wp-admin pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41207/how-do-i-enqueue-styles-scripts-on-certain-wp-admin-pages)

Comment: Use `admin_enqueue_scripts` instead of `admin_init`.

Comment: Glad to help! I see this issue far too often, unfortunately, and I think it is due to legacy code.