# Loading a stylesheet on a specific page

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-enqueue-style

I have a settings page under a custom post type menu.

The url for the page is like this - /wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=movies&page=movies_settings

How do I load the stylesheet just on that page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This covers it pretty well https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41207/how-do-i-enqueue-styles-scripts-on-certain-wp-admin-pages

Answer (score 0):

Try using parent and child class to use css on specific page

```
<div class="top-container"><span class="header-text"> content here</span> </div>
```

Assign a page level class .top-container{}
And then assign use it as a parent class for styling rest of elements on page

```
.top-container .header-text{}
```

You do not need to load a separate stylesheet rather than you can load a part of your css file for that specific page